# List of security protocols that have been proved to have bugs using formal methods

Tags: cryptanalysis, protocol-analysis, proverif

I'm looking for articles about finding bugs in security protocols using formal methods so I can test them using tools like [ProVerif](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/proverif/).

I've searched a lot of references, but most of them seem to be about formal methods themselves and why we should use them, not testing a particular security protocol.

Are there any security protocols that have been proved to have bugs by using formal methods?

Comment: Don't know, but WPA2 was proven secure from design and implementation and yet still was horribly broken. You can prove specific claims. we can never prove "Security"